# Statistical test for probability of survival across different doses

Tags: probability, survival, mortality

I have 8 different doses of a chemical and the mortality rate of each group exposed to the chemical. I want to compare the probability of survival across various doses. What sort of statistical analysis would fit here?

| Dose | Mortality |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | .214563 |
| 1.45 | .366522 |
| 1.68 | .414758 |

Comment: What kind of survival model are you using? Cox proportional hazards? Kaplan-Meier? Something else? (Also: Welcome to CV, Elasso!)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not looking at survival as a function of time, but rather each group was exposed to the chemical for a finite amount of time, and mortality rate is the proportion of deaths to survival after that time. Hope that answers the question

Comment: How many groups? Sounds like somewhat apt for a $\chi^{2}$ test in a contingency table analysis… although that will not capture the "trend" from increasing doses… just that there is a dependency on category of dose.

Comment: 8 groups exposed to different doses. I think I am supposed to be running a glm here but I wanted to get other opinions.

Comment: Have you thought of logistic regression? Assuming you have the sample sizes.

Comment: You are correct, and that's what I'm doing now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what kind of data you have. If in four groups
you have survivals 11, 15, 5, and 20 out of 40, 50, 40, and 40
subjects, respectively, then you can use a chi-squared test of homogeneity
or, equivalently, in R you can use `prop.test` as shown below.

The small P-value indicates that the four proportions of successes
are not all the same. Then you could use *ad hoc* tests (with
appropriate protection against 'false discovery', making multiple
tests on the same data; the Bonferroni method is one possibility.)

```
prop.test(c(11,15,5, 20), c(40,50,40,40))

        4-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(11, 15, 5, 20) out of c(40, 50, 40, 40)
X-squared = 13.571, df = 3, p-value = 0.003551
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 prop 4 
 0.275  0.300  0.125  0.500
```

If this is not the kind of data you meant to describe, please
edit your question for clarity.

Comment: I edited to show the format of the data. I don't need to know if the proportions of successes in each group are different, I need to fit a model that shows the relationship between dose and mortality. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Elasso You should also add the sample sizes in each group. BruceET and I are thinking along quite similar lines in this answer and my comment above. I would add a (very tiny) caveat that you could also use a likelihood ratio test ([$G$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test)) instead of the more common $\chi^{2}$.

Comment: Sample size was around 50 for each dose. I'm a little confused about how the chi-square test would tell me anything here. I know these values are not due to chance. I need to generate a regression line and be able to predict values and whatnot.

Comment: So exactly what do you mean by the vague and (apparently) uninformative "compare the probability of survival across various doses"? Seems you're somehow taking for granted that the groups must differ, and maybe want to predict that from (an undisclosed pattern of) doses. // I think a total edit of your Question is in order, not just bits of hints in Comments.

Comment: Sorry, but that's literally all the information I have from the question prompt. I've figured out what I need to do though, it's a glm with a logit link.